# Facebook Graph Batch Call Problems: Using C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Goal:
I want to pass in a lat/long and a radius(1000 meters) to return all the businesses in the circle. Then, of those businesses, I weant to gather all the checkin data from my friends.
I want to do this using the Batch Graph API call.

The first part is working fine:

```
new FacebookBatchParameter("/search?type=place&center=47.668451,-122.334788&distance=100", new { limit = 0 }) { Data = new { name = "tangle", omit_response_on_success = false } },
```

This gets the correct businesses for the 100 meters around my latlong.

```
new FacebookBatchParameter { Parameters = new { ids = "{result=tangle:$.data.*.id}/checkins" } },
```

The second part does not work. It reuturns an error :
(OAuthException) (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 297153575844/checkins

This is broken because when I manually put the "297153575844/checkins" into the graph API it works fine.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?